# Java URL Connection strange behavior on https URLs

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

```
    public class URLConnectionReader {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            URL urlObj = new URL("https://www.paypal.com"); // enter url here
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(code);
        }
}
```

I am creating a URL Tester which checks if URL is working or not .above is my code. when I test it with https://www.paypal.com it returns 200 and when I test it with https://www.facebook.com it throws exception.
Below is the exception stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at URLConnectionReader.main(URLConnectionReader.java:27)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)

at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 17 more
```

can anybody please explain me why https://www.paypal.com returns 200 but https://www.facebook.com throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is that Java by default comes with a very limited set
>   of root CA certificates. It "accepts" far fewer CAs than a typical
>   browser. The simplest way to solve the problem is to export a set of
>   CA certificates from a browser like Chrome or Firefox and import them
>   into Java's keystore using [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html).

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334441/java-refusing-certificate-that-browser-accepts)

Comment: Don't post answers that are essentially a quote from another question, instead vote or flag to close as duplicate.

Comment: i can't see duplicate flag in flags

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit, because the text in the answer isn't yours, so it must be quoted and attributed. Your edit removed the fact it was a quote and removed the attribution, which would make your answer breaking the rules (specifically plagiary). Flagging as duplicate might need slightly higher reputation, not sure.

Comment: I didn't know that I can flag the post as a duplicate.Thanks.I got it

Comment: FYI : @MarkRotteveel we need 15rep to be able to [flag a post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), no more. _ebrahim poursadeqi_, you can see more information on that privilege in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Because paypal has a certificate that was signed by an authority that is in your trustStore, whereas facebook doesn't.